# Excel filtering/extracting data based on a couple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the following data in Excel:

| application | version |
| --- | --- |
| app_01 | 1.0 |
| app_01 | 2.0 |
| app_02 | 2.0 |
| app_02 | 2.0 |
| app_03 | 1.0 |
| app_03 | 2.0 |
| app_03 | 3.0 |

I'm looking for a way to filter and display applications with more than one distinct version. First condition would be 1) application values need to match, then 2) if versions under those applications do NOT match, then display those rows. So, the expected output should be something like this:

| application | version |
| --- | --- |
| app_01 | 1.0 |
| app_01 | 2.0 |
| app_03 | 1.0 |
| app_03 | 2.0 |
| app_03 | 3.0 |

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> & <kbd>COUNTIFS( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=FILTER(A2:B8,COUNTIFS(A2:A8,A2:A8,B2:B8,B2:B8)=1)
```

---

Or, Use <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> with <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,A2:A8&"|"&B2:B8,
     σ,N(α=TOROW(α)),
     FILTER(A2:B8,MMULT(σ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(σ),,,0))=1))
```

---

I am not sure whether this works for your query or not, found even <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> function would simply do the job. This is because, you need those which **do not** have same **versions** and the **applications** should **match**, which is actually getting the ones which have appeared only once. So the last parameter of <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> does that (`TRUE` / `1` --> `Return items that appear exactly once`).

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B8,,1)
```

---